# "SQL syntax error" DO NADA depois de 1 ano funcionando

Tags: php, sql

Durante 1 ano o software da minha empresa funcionou se problemas, até que em um belo dia do nada acontece isso (está nos dando muita dor de cabeça e custo):

```
    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in 
your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'get FROM Acompanhamento WHERE alunoid = '2767' 
and excluido = 0 ORDER BY data de' at line 1' in /.../dao/DboObject.php:27
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 /.../DboObject.php(27): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /.../AcompanhamentoAlunoDao.php(24): DboObject->select('SELECT id, peso...', Array)
#2 /.../AcompanhamentoAlunoBo.php(19): AcompanhamentoAlunoDao->select('alunoid = ? and...', Array)
#3 /.../ficha_de_acompanhamento.php(38): AcompanhamentoAlunoBo->getAcompanhamentoByAluno('2767')
#4 {main}
  thrown in /.../DboObject.php on line 27
```

Código nos arquivos mencionados pelo Stack Trace (coloquei ** no começo e final das linhas específicas mencionadas pelo stack trace).

DboObject.php:

```
public function select($sql='',$args){
        $this->query = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        **$this->query->execute($args);**
        $this->result = $this->query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
```

AcompanhamentoAlunoDao.php:

```
parent::select($sql, $args);
```

AcompanhamentoAlunoBo.php:

```
public function getAcompanhamentoByAluno($alunoId,$campo=null){
        **$query = "alunoid = ? and excluido = 0 ";**
        if(!is_null($campo)){
            $query.= "and ".$campo." is not null ";
        }
```

ficha_de_acompanhamento.php:

```
$acompanhamento = $acompanhamentoAlunoBo->getAcompanhamentoByAluno($AlunoId);
```

O que é muito estranho é o fato de ter funcionado por tanto tempo e sem uma linha de código ser alterada apresentar esse problema.

Comment: Qual o valor de `$sql` e `$args` passado para o `select`?

Comment: Nada mudou ? Versão ? Na tabela ? Software não é tomate , não estraga. :)